# Order of the subgroup of traceless matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, trace, noncommutative-algebra

Let $M_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ denote the ring of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in the finite field of $q$ elements, for prime $q$.

1. How many elements of $M_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ have zero trace? and
2. Since every trace zero element of $M_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ can be written as a commutator of two matrices, am I right in thinking that $\#\{x\in M_n(\mathbb{F}_q):Tr(x) = 0\} = |[M_n(\mathbb{F}_q),M_n(\mathbb{F}_q)]|$, where $[\cdot,\cdot]$ denotes the additive commutator and $[M_n(\mathbb{F}_q),M_n(\mathbb{F}_q)]$ is the subgroup of $M_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ additively generated by all commutators? If not,
3. What is $|[M_n(\mathbb{F}_q),M_n(\mathbb{F}_q)]|$?

Comment: **Hint :** The set of zero-trace matrices is an hyperplane of $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$, since it is the kernel of the trace (which is a linear form).

Comment: So the zero-trace matrices are an $n^2-1$ dimensional subspace? Does that mean there are $q^{n^2-1}$ of them?

Comment: Indeed ! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @a196884: Concretely, to make a trace-zero matrix, you can start by choosing, say, all elements _except_ the lower right one completely freely. After that, there will be exactly one value of the remaining element that will make the trace vanish (namely, minus the sum of the diagonal elements you've already chosen).